# Process builder not firing for managed package object

Tags: managed-package, process-builder, custom-object, visual-workflow

I have a process builder that I want to fire when a record changes.  This record is an Answer object which is apart of the Youreka managed package.  I have created a simple process builder that is supposed to fire when the Answer record is related to a Question record where the Type field has the value Attachment/Photo.Once these conditions are met, it will kick off my flow and pass the ID of the answer record into my flow.

I have tested and debugged the flow by manually passing in an answer record ID and everything functions as expected. However, when I try to fire my flow using the PB (by changing a record) nothing happens. It doesn't even seem to fire the flow. I know this is the case because nothing appears in the debug logs even though I get a flow message in the debug log when I fire it manually. Is there a setting I am missing here? I am not sure if it is because I am trying to fire this PB using a managed package object or not.

[image: Flow Action in PB]

[image: Flow Criteria in PB]

[image: Answer PB]

Comment: Have you activated the Flow?

Comment: Yep both the PB and Flow are activated.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use an auto-launch flow instead of this PB/flow combo?

Answer (score 0):

There's no special reason why a managed package object would behave different.  I'd bet the criteria doesn't match in the decision diamond.  To test this theory, add an email alert to yourself along the "false" path.  If you get the email, the PB doesn't have the correct criteria to fire.

PB can be strange with relationship fields.  Perhaps the Question__r portion isn't populated yet by the time the PB is fired?